# IDA Free and _time64 decompilation?

Tags: c++, time, disassembly, decompiling

I'm trying to understand this line specifically: `now_int = time64(0);`

Reading the docs for [time, _time32, _time64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=msvc-170), `time64()` accepts a pointer or `NULL` and should return a `__time64_t` type.

In the decompiled code, it takes a parameter `0` and returns the current UNIX timestamp.

```cpp
int unknown_seed_stuff()
{
    int now_int; // eax
    double now_double; // xmm0_8

    now_int = time64(0);
    srand(now_int);
    now_double = (double)time64(0);
    if ( now_double >= 2147483647.0 )
        now_double = now_double * 0.5;
    prng_seed_0 = now_double;
    dword_FF9268 = time64(0) ^ 0xC;
    return atexit(nullsub_141);
}
```

This is the disassembly for the code above.

```
.text:00413CB0 unknown_seed_stuff proc near            ; DATA XREF: .rdata:00D263D0↓o
.text:00413CB0                 push    esi
.text:00413CB1                 mov     esi, ds:_time64
.text:00413CB7                 push    0               ; Time
.text:00413CB9                 call    esi ; _time64
.text:00413CBB                 push    eax             ; Seed
.text:00413CBC                 call    ds:srand
.text:00413CC2                 push    0               ; Time
.text:00413CC4                 call    esi ; _time64
.text:00413CC6                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:00413CC9                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:00413CCB                 call    __ltod3
.text:00413CD0                 comisd  xmm0, ds:MAXINT
.text:00413CD8                 jb      short loc_413CE2
.text:00413CDA                 mulsd   xmm0, ds:qword_E69F70
.text:00413CE2
.text:00413CE2 loc_413CE2:                             ; CODE XREF: unknown_seed_stuff+28↑j
.text:00413CE2                 push    0               ; Time
.text:00413CE4                 movsd   prng_seed_0, xmm0
.text:00413CEC                 call    esi ; _time64
.text:00413CEE                 xor     eax, 0Ch
.text:00413CF1                 push    offset nullsub_141 ; void (__cdecl *)()
.text:00413CF6                 mov     dword_FF9268, eax
.text:00413CFB                 call    _atexit
.text:00413D00                 add     esp, 8
.text:00413D03                 pop     esi
.text:00413D04                 retn
.text:00413D04 unknown_seed_stuff endp
```

And that's at the offset of `ds:_time64` (when time64() is called):

```
.idata:00D25410 ; __time64_t (__cdecl *time64)(__time64_t *Time)
.idata:00D25410 _time64         dd offset msvcr120__time64
.idata:00D25410                                         ; CODE XREF: unknown_seed_stuff+9↑p
.idata:00D25410                                         ; unknown_seed_stuff+14↑p ...
```

Why does it accept `0` instead of a pointer or `NULL`, and why does it not return a `__time64_t` type but the value of the timestamp (as int32 no less)?

Comment: I might misunderstand your question, but `NULL` is the same as `0`?

Comment: `0` is a [null pointer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Null_pointers), same as `NULL`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I thought NULL would be `time64()` (without the `0`). If so, that leaves only the question of the return type/value.

Comment: What makes you believe it doesn't return `__time64_t` type? The calling code happens not to use the high-order bits, but that doesn't mean the function didn't return them.

Comment: The timestamp is passed by `eax`, a 32-bit register. If it would be a 64-bit value, it would have been passed by `rax` or by a pointer, no? And with the special type, I would expect it to be a pointer in all cases.

Comment: Couldn't it be because you assign it to a 32-bit integer `int now_int;`? So it's only reading the lower 32-bit because that's all that can fit in an int anyway.

Comment: On x64 architecture, `eax` is an alias to lower 32 bits of `rax`. I'm not sure what you mean by "special type"; I expect `__time64_t` is merely a typedef for `long long` or similar.